# Issue in copying file from local file system to hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

While firing this command, it throws an error

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /home/osboxes/sample new
```

> copyFromLocal: `new': No such file or directory"

Comment: What do `echo $(whoami)` and `hdfs dfs -ls` give you?

Comment: whoami gives me "osboxes" and for hdfs dfs -ls gives"
ls: `.': No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

> hdfs dfs -ls gives" ls: `.': No such file or directory"

You don't have a HDFS user directory to copy anything into

Verify by `hdfs dfs -ls /user | grep $(whoami)`

You need to make this folder before you can really do anything useful such as running MapReduce, or copying files into the relative path of the user folder such as you've done

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p "/user/$(whoami)"
hdfs dfs -chown -R $(whoami) "/user/$(whoami)"
```

Then run your copy command

Or give a different path `hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal file /tmp/somePlace`

Comment: copyFromLocal: `home/osboxes/sample': No such file or directory

Comment: Missed a leading slash on `/home`